# What does word "monster" referring to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Fast X (2023), Ramsey says to Han about God's Eye being misused:

> Ramsey: God's Eye was just used to send dozens of mercenaries after Dom's son.
> Something I created hurting the people we love. It was meant to help.
> This is bigger than just Dante. This is bigger than just us. We have to
> stop this **monster** now.

What does word "monster" referring to?

Comment: The phrasing isn't brilliant. The first ***this** is bigger than just us* can only refer to the current overall situation, but the second one *(**this** monster)* almost certainly refers specifically to ***God's Eye*** (whatever that means - I haven't seen the movie).

Comment: Have you checked dictionaries? On this site, people asking questions are expected to do the basic research on their own, including looking up words in dictionaries. If you've already done this and are still not sure, we're required to include what we found in the question and explain why it's in sufficient. One search for "monster" at Merriam-Webster turned up quite a reasonable definition.

Comment: The God's Eye (*created by Ramsey*)  is able to hack any type of technology using a camera and satellite tracking. It feeds information gathered back to its user "under four minutes or less" to use to their whims. The God's Eye works at its best when it's close enough to its target to track, but can locate any given person at great distances. The God's Eye, however, is not impervious to being compromised by another hacking device or hacker. As demonstrated by its creator, it is capable of being taken over by anyone within its range. [source](https://fastandfurious.fandom.com/wiki/God%27s_Eye).